# Mac OS X: where app can create a log file?

Tags: c++, macos

My app creates its log file like this

```
FILE *ftemp = NULL;
ftemp=fopen("/var/log/x.log", "ab+");
if(ftemp) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ftemp: log created\n");
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ftemp: log error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

The output is:

```
ftemp: log error:Permission denied
```

I will deploy it to other machines.
Is there any location where my app has permissions to create its log file on any other machines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your program runs as root (which it apparently does not, judging from your “Permission denied” error), either `/var/log` or `/Library/Logs` is appropriate.

If your program runs as an ordinary user, `~/Library/Logs` is appropriate.

It would be appropriate to create a subdirectory (in whatever log directory you end up using) named after your program, and write your logs in the subdirectory. For example, Apache on macOS writes its logs to `/var/log/apache2` by default; the Notes app writes its logs to `~/Library/Logs/com.apple.Notes`.

If your program runs as a system account (not root but not an ordinary user account), then perhaps your installer can create the log subdirectory under `/var/log` or `/Library/Logs` as root, then `chown` it to that system account to make it writable by your program.

Comment: Thanx. Btw, when the app received the "permission error" I  try to fprintf(stderr, "Error: permissions...") but where I can find the stderr output? My app is app with GUI.

Comment: If you launch a GUI app by double-clicking it, `stderr` is redirected to `/dev/null`, so you cannot find the output anywhere. You should use `NSLog` or `os_log` instead of printing to `stderr`. Then you can find your output using the `log` command or in Console.app (*if* you launch Console.app before your app logs the message).