# Where to save CLI application log file that will work cross-platform?

Tags: node.js, logging

I have an application that saves error logs into the same directory where the script was run. This is bad because it creates `error.log` files in random places. So I want to save the file into /var/log on GNU/Linux and I would like to have the same for Windows and macOS (and probably any other OS where NodeJS runs).

Is there a cross-platform way to get a log directory? So I can write logs there?
Also how to work with that directory if it's owned by root. Or is there a better place to save NodeJS application logs?

The only directory cross-platform NodeJS directory is `/tmp` using:

```js
const log_filename = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'lips.error.log');
```

What is the best place to save logs where users can look them up? Same directory and /tmp directory are not good options in my option. What are the other options to save logs files?

What is the usual place where log files should be saved cross-platform in any CLI application?

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the fun -- there is no single directory to store logs, so you'll need to handle each supported OS separately.

- [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104936/310780) has options, but it would be good to go for the XDG specification way, as it's a reasonable standard that won't fill up system logs, and it will make it simple to isolate the applications logs.
- [macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49145655/7665043) can use the `~/Library/logs` folder.
- [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1572934/7665043) can use the `AppData` folder, usually `AppData/Local`.